# Serial ports stopped working when upgraded to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, serial-port

I've been using GTKTerm on Ubuntu version 18 happily with a dual PCI serial RS232 card for a while. On upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 it's stopped working. Ports seem to be found by system (ttyS4 & 5):-

```
$ setserial -g -v /dev/ttyS[0123456]
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS4, UART: 16650V2, Port: 0xc010, IRQ: 18
/dev/ttyS5, UART: 16650V2, Port: 0xc000, IRQ: 19
```

I have a loopback cable on the port and when I boot machine into windows it works fine. I have also looped back handshake lines but it still doesn't help. What's odd is GTKTerm is obviously opening the port and talking to the card as the options to toggle RTS and DTR are working (I've put a scope on the pins and they go up and down) but hitting a key in the terminal does not produce any activity on Tx pin and data applied to Rx is not displayed. Various handshaking options in GTKTerm have been tried and both ports on serial card are the same. Also tried minicom. I am a member of dialout group.

No errors are reported anywhere. PCI serial card based on Moschip mcs9900 device. Suppliers CD with drivers for card says to recompile kernel with stuff added which is beyond me and it worked before without such faff.

Any help welcome.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I used 2 pcie dual-port serial interfaces PEX2S952 from Startech successfully on CentOS 5. Here it created 4 tty ports. I installed these same 2 pcie serial interfaces into a PC with a clean installation of Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS. Even though the kernel indicates the proper pcie and kernel boot logs for these, neither device will work. If I remove either one of the interfaces the remaining interface does work. I have not gotten this to work with 2 interfaces.

Comment: Hi, I never solved it. Ended up using a USB-Serial convertor.